# Deleting large volumes of data from database using .NetCore

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to delete over 5000 records from the database using .netCore 2.1. I have the following method which works fine however it takes way too long.

```
public async Task<bool> deleteAdhocDetails(int[] id)
{
    var status = false;

    for (var x = 0; x < id.Length; x++)
    {
        var existingReward = await _context.AdhocRewardInfo
            .Where(d => d.RowID == id[x])
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync<AdhocRewardInfo>();

        if ((existingReward != null) && (existingReward.HaloRewardCode != null))
        {
            try
            {
                //removing existingReward
                _context.AdhocRewardInfo.Remove(existingReward);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                status = true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }
    return status;
}
```

I am currently using EFCore.BulkExtensions for inserting records and it works nicely. I tried using BulkDelete but it didn't seem to make a difference. I also tried to use Z.EntityFramework.Extensions.EFCore but couldn't get that to work too. I should also mention that I am kinda new to this. If someone could please point me in the right direction I would appreciate it. Thanks

In the adhoc.service.ts:

```
deleteAdhocRecipients(id: number[]): Promise<boolean> {
    return this.http.put<boolean>(this.baseUrl + 'deleteAdhocDetails', id)
      .toPromise();
    }
```

and in the .ts file:

```
this.general
  .load(this.aService.deleteAdhocCampaign(this.adhocForm.get('create.id').value))
  .then(
    y => {
      if (deleteArr.length > 0) {
        this.general.load(this.aService.deleteAdhocRecipients(deleteArr))
          .then(
            f => this.router.navigate(['/adhoc-campaign/lookup'])
          );
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(['/adhoc-campaign/lookup']);
      }
    }
  );
```

Comment: Not like this. EF Core is an ORM - it Maps Objects to Relational tables. ORMs aren't meant for batch or report operations. There are no Objects in this case, just rows. `using EFCore.BulkExtensions for inserting records and it works nicely.` not really. EF Core has no such capability. What this class does under the hood is convert the objects to rows and use SqlBulkCopy to do the same thing `BULK INSERT` would do. There's no `BULK DELETE`, these extensions (actually from the same author) just writhe the same DELETE statements you would

Comment: There are a lot of problems with this code btw, inclugind serious misused of EF Core. `SaveChanges` is meant to be used just *once*, to persist and commit the changes to the database. You could write `_context.AdhocRewardInfo.Where(d => ids.Contains(d.RowID)` to load all related entities, call `Remove` on them in a loop and only *after* the loop call `SaveChanges` *once*. EF Core will generate and execute the DELETE statements. This would still be a lot slower than `DELETE someTable where Id in (1,2,3,4..)` but a lot faster than executing one DELETE after the other

Comment: Is there a reason you need to save in the loop?

Comment: Where do these IDs come from? You could write a `DELETE ... WHERE` query with a condition that generates the IDs to avoid having to work with individual IDs. If the list comes from an external file  uou can use Dapper to easily write a parameterize `DELETE`, eg `connection.Execute("DELETE from MyTable where ID in @ids",new {ids=id});`. Unfortunately, `IN` works with up to around 2000 items. Another option is to insert all IDs into a temporary/staging table and write `DELETE MyTable from MyTable inner join tempTable on MyTable.ID=TempTable.ID`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, thank you for your advice and your suggestion, I will try it out.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I edited the post to show where the IDs come from, hope that helps

Comment: [EF Core Tools & Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/) - use some extensions from here (search for "delete" term on the page). I'd recommend linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore.

Comment: EFCore.BulkExtensions should work fast. I think you should ask a new separate question about this library.

Answer (score 0):

I optimized your c# code

```
public async Task<bool> deleteAdhocDetails(int[] id){
  try{
  var deletedRecords= await _context.AdhocRewardInfo.Where(d => 
  id.Contains(d.RowID))

  foreach (var item in deletedRecords)
  {
    _context.AdhocRewardInfo.Remove(item );
  }
  await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
  return true;
  }catch (Exception e){
    return false;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove select of object and then do only one saveChanges

```cs
        public async Task<bool> deleteAdhocDetails((int id, object haloRewardCode)[] id)
        {
            try
            {
                for (var x = 0; x < id.Length; x++)
                {
                    var existingReward = new AdhocRewardInfo() { id = id[x].id, HaloRewardCode = id[x].haloRewardCode };

                    if ((existingReward != null) && (existingReward.HaloRewardCode != null))
                    {
                        //removing existingReward
                       _context.AdhocRewardInfo.Remove(existingReward);
                   }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw;
            }

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: This won't work.  `existingReward != null` is meaningless since you just created the object, but `existingReward.HaloRewardCode != null` will always fail because that value wasn't set. The original code deletes only the objects that have a `HaloRewardCode` value

Comment: Have you apply a global query filter? if not, remove this check and try again... why do you need HaloRewardCode for delete?

Comment: I don't. The OP does. Check the query again. It's not just removing every object that matches the ID, it's removing the object that has a specific non-null property.

Comment: can you pass id and HaloRewardCode into this method?

Comment: i change method for passing id and haloRewardCode... i wish you can do this... anyway you need to do the select before the cicle... that slow down the performance.... like karagoz say await _context.AdhocRewardInfo.Where(d => 
  id.Contains(d.RowID))

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore) (disclaimer: I'm one of the creators).

And `Delete` will be fast as possible:

```cs
var deletedCount = await _context.AdhocRewardInfo
    .Where(d => id.Contains(d.RowID))
    .DeleteAsync();
```

Comment: I tried using your suggestion but was met with 'DataContext' is an ambiguous reference between "DataContext' and 'LinqToDB.DataContext'.

Comment: Probably you have your own `DataContext` class, so specify full path. Extension based on  ORM `linq2db` and class names may duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I think the fastest way will be using sql query string

```
public async Task<bool> deleteAdhocDetails(int[] id)
{

var ids= string.Join(",",id);
var rows= await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(
"DELETE FROM AdhocRewardInfo WHERE  Id IN ("+ ids +  ")");

return rows>0;
}
```

Comment: This is fine for smaller number of IDs but it gets really slow towards 32,000 items and fails a bit over that. What to do then?

Comment: It is the fastest that can be used.  A little more faster will be if you create a stored procedure using this sql script.

Comment: No I meant there’s a limit on how many items work in an IN statement and as you approach the limit sql becomes very slow.

Comment: @Rory you can separate ids for 2 parts for example, and compare the times. But I don't think that you will see the big difference.  You can check if you have ID index. It will make faster.  What I mean is that stored procedure is the fastest way to run any query. There is nothing faster.

Comment: I wasn’t very clear initially - I meant like https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/228982 which shows SQL Server takes many seconds (parse/compile perhaps?) to execute statements approaching 32k items in an IN clause. So while I like & use this approach one needs to be careful if there could be many thousands of items. Then you need to chop into several statements … or something like that. I don’t know if the EFCore.BulkExtensions does that automatically, but using .BatchDelete() seems to generate the DELETE FROM x WHERE Id IN (…) statement, which is handy.

Comment: @Rory In any case even it it generates DELETE FROM x WHERE Id IN (…) ,  at least it has  one more step, then a stored procedure. plus stored procedure maybe precompiled